# js-ctypes invalid arguments

Tags: javascript, windows, smartcard, jsctypes

Iam trying to run winscard functions using js-ctypes in Firefox.
I have working C code and I started to copy code to javascipt.
Unfortunetly my first function- SCardEstablishContext returns the following error:

> SCARD_E_INVALID_PARAMETER 0x80100004

Whats wrong with the arguments?

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");
const NULL = ctypes.voidptr_t(0);

var cardLib = ctypes.open("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WinSCard.dll");
var SCardEstablishContext = cardLib.declare("SCardEstablishContext", ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.uint32_t, ctypes.uint32_t, ctypes.voidptr_t, ctypes.voidptr_t, ctypes.voidptr_t);
var ContextHandle = new ctypes.voidptr_t();
var ret = SCardEstablishContext(2, NULL, NULL, ContextHandle);
cardLib.close();
```

Comment: Hey @Karol have you uploaded your work to github yet? I did some work to list all the readers here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32169381/1828637 I would love to see the addon you make out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter of SCardEstablishContext (`phContext`) should be a pointer to a 32-bit integer. Upon success, SCardEstablishContext populates this integer value with the handle to the SCARD context.

You define `ContextHandle` as new uninitialized instance of `ctypes.voidptr_t`, which is essentially the same as `ctypes.voidptr_t(0)` (hence, a null-pointer). You then pass this null-pointer to SCardEstablishContext, which, conequently, cannot assign a value (as the reference/pointer is not backed by actual data memory).

Thus, you should define `ContextHandle` as a voidptr_t (32-bit integer on 32-bit platforms / 64-bit integer on 64-bit platforms)

```
var ContextHandle = ctypes.voidptr_t(0);
```

and then pass **the pointer** to this `ContextHandle` to the SCardEstablishContext function:

```
var ret = SCardEstablishContext(2, NULL, NULL, ContextHandle.address());
```

Comment: I think the persons problem as they werent doing `ContextHandle.address()` with that and `ctypes.voidptr_t` it works, however its really awesome to know that `CARDCONTEXT` is a 32bit int, i couldnt find that typedef so i just use `voidptr_t`. If its a 32bit int, then on 64bit system ctypes.int will be 64bit so we would have to force it 32bit with another ctypes type.

Comment: `ctypes.uint32_t` would be the 32bit integer if so if we wnated to be accurate we would do this: `var SCARDCONTEXT = ctypes.uint32_t;` and `var LPSCARDCONTEXT = SCARDCONTEXT.ptr;`

Comment: @Noitidart Not quite, on Windows `int` and `long` (SCARDCONTEXT is typedef'd as `long` are 32-bit for both platforms (32-bit and 64-bit Windows). `voidptr_t` is 32-bit on 32-bit platforms and 64-bit on 64-bit platforms. Thus, `voidptr_t` won't match the definition of SCARDCONTEXT. The contract for `ctypes.int` is to follow the platform's definition of `int`. Hence, `ctypes.int` will be a 32-bit integer that matches the definition of `int` and `long` on Windows.

Comment: Ah very interesting @Michael do you do js-ctypes yourself? That is some cool analysis!

Comment: it seems the typdef for `SCARDCONTEXT` is `ULONG_PTR` is this correct? https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/b75cd7e2f0f6f40655f690695ab0843fce472e88/include/winscard.h#L37

Comment: You seem to be right. I was fooled by the pcsc-lite implementation. `SCARDCONTEXT` is indeed a `ULONG_PTR`. In that case using `voidptr_t`instead of `int` is correct.

Comment: Thanks veyr much @micahel for your help. I'm trying to help this guy here with a spoon feed, do you have a card reader by chance and would you be able to test the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32169381/1828637

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you need to pass `ContextHandle.address()` you only pass `ContextHandle`.

## Here's my style of code:

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm');
//const NULL = ctypes.voidptr_t(0); // no need for this, just use js null

var is64bit = ctypes.voidptr_t.size == 4 ? false : true;
var TYPES = {
  ABI: is64bit ? ctypes.default_abi : ctypes.winapi_abi,
  CALLBACK_ABI: is64bit ? ctypes.default_abi : ctypes.stdcall_cabi,
  DWORD: ctypes.unsigned_long,
  LPCVOID: ctypes.voidptr_t,
  LPSCARDCONTEXT: ctypes.voidptr_t
}

var CONST = {
  SCARD_SCOPE_USER: 0,
  SCARD_SCOPE_SYSTEM: 2,
  SCARD_S_SUCCESS: 0
};

var cardLib = ctypes.open('Winscard');

var SCardEstablishContext = cardLib.declare("SCardEstablishContext", TYPES.ABI, TYPES.DWORD, TYPES.DWORD, TYPES.LPCVOID, TYPES.LPCVOID, TYPES.LPSCARDCONTEXT);

var ContextHandle = TYPES.LPSCARDCONTEXT();
var ret = SCardEstablishContext(CONST.SCARD_SCOPE_SYSTEM, null, null, ContextHandle.address());

console.info('ret:', ret, ret.toString());

if (ret.toString() != CONST.SCARD_S_SUCCESS.toString()) {
  console.error('failed to establish context! error code was: ' + ret + ' in other terms it is: 0x' + ret.toString(16) + ' you can look up this error value here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#smart_card_return_values');
}

cardLib.close();
```

It wont work for me has i dont have a card reader it keeps giving me error `0x8010001d` which is `SCARD_E_NO_SERVICE` per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#smart_card_return_values and this totally makes sense as my computer has no card reader.

But this code works and shows you how to see the error you get as well :) Keep up the awesome work and keep posting here if you need help!

There's also jsctypes channel on moz irc servers. Can copy paste this url into your firefox: `irc://moznet/jsctypes`